# Derivations on the continuous functions of a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, cotangent-bundles

For a manifold $M$ a **vector field** is a derivation of the algebra $C^{\infty}(M)$ of smooth functions on $M$. What happens if look instead as derivations on the continuous functions of a manifold. I guess we get fewer derivations . . .  but I'm not sure how one might prove this.

Comment: This is also answered in one of the *related* questions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15448/derivations-of-cx-or-why-must-supermanifolds-be-smooth

Answer (score 12, accepted):

More is true: if $X$ is a topological manifold, then in fact $\operatorname{Der}(C(X)) = 0$, where $C(X)$ denotes the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$-valued continuous functions on $X$. In particular, this is so for smooth manifolds $M$.

Here is one proof: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derivation#DerOfContFuncts

Comment: I expected that the set of derivations would be smaller, but the fact that there are none is quite surprising! Thanks for the answe and the link!

Comment: @DaveShulman: You are welcome! Happy to help!